# Exposing local Docker daemon to minikube - Jenkins config.json: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: jenkins, kubectl, minikube

I'm running Jenkins on Windows 10,installed Docker toolbox and minikube (also on Windows 10).

I can "map" local Docker images to minikube with this Powershell command:  `minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression`, everything works as expected.

I want to do the same using Jenkinsfile

```
stage('Build1') {
         steps {
            powershell """
            minikube docker-env | Invoke-Expression
            """

         }
      }
```

But Jenkins is looking for config.json file in wrong location:

```
powershell.exe : * 
At C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\api-gateway_master@tmp\durable-355fdbbe\powershellWrapper.ps1:3 char:1
+ & powershell -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Comm ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (* :String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

X Error getting config: CreateFile C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.minikube\profiles\minikube\config.json: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

config file is actually in userprofile path:`C:\Users\username\.minikube\profiles\minikube\config.json`.

Same error with shell command (Git for Windows)

```
stage('Build1') {
         steps {
           sh 'eval $(minikube docker-env)'

         }
      }



++ minikube docker-env
* 
X Error getting config: CreateFile C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\.minikube\profiles\minikube\config.json: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Also created brad new minikube with this switch:-`-insecure-registry windows 10 IP:5000`

**EDIT:After applying suggestion as per comment:**

Created environment variable in Jenkins:

```
MINIKUBE_HOME=C:\Users\user\.minikube
```

Now getting:

```
++ minikube docker-env
* 
X Error getting host status
* Error: [MACHINE_DOES_NOT_EXIST] state: machine does not exist
* Suggestion: Run 'minikube delete' to delete the stale VM, or and ensure that minikube is running as the same user you are issuing this command with
```

Did `minikube stop`, deleted minikube VM from Virtual Box,deleted folder `C:\Users\user\.minikube`, `minikube start`, no errors, but when running Jenkins pipeline, same error.

Comment: Can you set in Jenkins pipeline definition env variable (MINIKUBE_HOME) to point the location of default config file?

Comment: @xerks, but you apparently made a step forward. Right now you need to specify the minikube's profile that holds a configuration of specific Minikube's VM instance. 
You can do this in two ways, either by adding '-p <profile_name>' to each of minikube subcommand, or set it globally with 'minikube profile' command once (check existing ones with 'minikube profile list').

Comment: Actually what's your ultimate goal, to just re-use Docker's daemon from Minikube's VM, or want to utilize minikube inside the CI pipeline. If the latter please check this tutorial:
https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/fb50cf8621df110e3d5654e783d5795e3c385ec0/site/content/en/docs/Tutorials/continuous_integration.md

Comment: i have mimikube as VirtualBox VM, Jenkins is installed locally on windows 10. I want expose docker images located on windows 10 to minikube

Comment: Please check my my answer, should solve your issue. btw. why you are running 'sh' step inside you pipeline on Windows instead 'powershell' ?, is your executor/slave/agent hosted on another machine - that would make your case more complex.

Comment: i tried sh just to see will it solve the issue, it did not :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to mess with minikube anymore

- uninstalled minikube
- uninstalled Docker Toolbox
- installed [Docker Desktop](https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows)
- On Docker desktop enabled Kubernetes (Settings-Kubernetes-enable Kubernetes)

Now all docker images are available to Kubernetes and Jenkins

Answer (score 2):

How about this, to make the 'minikube' integration smooth inside the Jenkins pipeline just apply the hint received on last error output.

> Ensure that minikube is running as the same user you are issuing this
>   command with.

Assuming your Jenkins master server is running as a Windows Service (in context of Local System account by default), change it to the dedicated local user account (e.g ".\user") - the same you have created your minikube instance with.

Another option: use dedicated [credentials](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/using/using-credentials/) with your Pipeline

Eventually you can switch into another setup (hard way):
**[Running Jenkins inside your (Minikube) Kubernetes cluster](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins)** with [Kubernetes plugin for Jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin) and [Docker-outside-of-Docker](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin/blob/4d0ddcc274c77a6b6530bd6cbc241da258df984d/examples/dood.groovy) groovy-based pipeline (it reuses host docker daemon - in your case from Minikube).

Comment: this works fine, no more errors in whole pipeline, used powershell for all the Jenkjns steps, but docker image created locally is not shown in minikube (mikube ssh && docker images)

Comment: that's weird, please double check if you don't have by chance two different Minikube VMs (=2 different docker registries), with 'minikube profile list'

Comment: You mentioned earlier you have a docker toolbox installed locally, didn't you push there your docker images instead of remote docker registry on Minikube ?

Comment: yes, docker images are stored "locally" (windows 10), when from CMD or Powerhshell type `docker images` i see all images i built with Jenkins pipeline. When i perform manually all commands (Powershell console) i specified in pipeline, all works fine, but when doing the same from Jenkins pipeline, local docker images are not "mapped/redirected" to minikube VM.I only have one minikube VM.

Comment: I'm not sure if we understand each other correctly. The point is that you might be using different docker registry "locally" (Windows 10) than the one coming with Minikube VM. I suspect you are using a docker-machine locally (docker toolbox). Please verify it in Powershell (locally) with command: "ls env:\DOCKER*"
Does it produce the same env variable settings as "minikube docker-env" inside Jenkins pipeline ?

Comment: from powershell `DOCKER_HOST tcp://172.16.0.102:2376`, it's IP of minikube.  minikube docker-env do not produce any output from Jenkins.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205737/discussion-between-nepomucen-and-xerks).